# How to count a group of similar category in csv python

Tags: python, csv

I am currently working on reading a csv file in python. I wanted the program to be able to count the number of 'Feedback'/'Complaints' etc whenever I run it.

Some example from the csv file is as follow:

```
Category        Description  
Feedback        Lighting
Feedback        Lighting
Complaints      Pest
Feedback        Lighting
Complaints      Pest
```

From the above, I wanted it to show something like

```
Total Feedback - 3
Description - Lighting
Total Complaints - 2
Description - Pest
```

How am I supposed to let it count the amount of feedback/what is the description.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Do you just want to count how many feedbacks or complaints are in the file or do you want to count how many feedbacks are `lighting` or anything else?

Comment: @skrx I want to count the total number of Feedbacks and complaints that are in the file.

Comment: Then you could use a `collections.Counter`. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the feedbacks and complaints.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter


counter = Counter()

with open('temp.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader, None)  # Skip the header.
    for category, description in reader:
        counter[category] += 1

print(counter)
# Counter({'Feedback': 3, 'Complaints': 2})
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try to import it in pandas:

```
`import pandas as pd


complaints = pd.read_csv('../data/311-service-requests.csv')
 print complaints.value_counts()
print complaints['complaint'].value_counts()
print complaints['feedback'].value_counts()`
```